# How to create a gradually-incrementing column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I create a column of data that increments gradually? EG. 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 etc

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (FirstName VARCHAR(50), LastName VARCHAR(50), Increment INT)

INSERT INTO #tmp (FirstName, LastName, Increment) SELECT 'Alice', 'Bell', NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp (FirstName, LastName, Increment) SELECT 'Charlie', 'Dickens', NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp (FirstName, LastName, Increment) SELECT 'Ernest', 'Fabio', NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp (FirstName, LastName, Increment) SELECT 'Graham', 'Holst', NULL
INSERT INTO #tmp (FirstName, LastName, Increment) SELECT 'India', 'Joplin', NULL

SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

Comment: What's the criteria for the increment?  How do we know to switch from 1 to 2?

Comment: use a sequence that starts at 3 and increments by 1 and divide the result by 3 and round down

Comment: How "gradual" ?

Comment: Do you want it for a `SELECT`? Or do you want to update the table? Or should this be created automatically upon `INSERT`? And what is defining the order? `lastname`? `lastname` and `firstname`?

Comment: You should really be using a Primary Key.  Also you have a possibility of repeating rows.  To be 1NF your data structure needs to have atomic values, a Primary Key, and ensure Non-Repeating rows.  You could solve the two problems by using an identity column as your PK.  That could further serve to implement the numbering scheme you're attempting (I would probably use an implementation of `rownum`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a table with a default constraint associated to a sequence.  If you want every third value to increment then just divide by three in the constraint:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MySeq  
    START WITH 3  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO 

CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    FirstName VARCHAR(50)
    , LastName VARCHAR(50)
    , Increment INT CONSTRAINT IncrementDefault DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [MySeq]/(3))
)
GO

INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName) SELECT 'Alice','Bell'
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName) SELECT 'Charlie','Dickens'
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName) SELECT 'Ernest','Fabio'
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName) SELECT 'Graham','Holst'
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName) SELECT 'India','Joplin'
```

The results will be

```
FirstName  | LastName  | Increment
Alice      | Bell      | 1
Charlie    | Dickens   | 1
Ernest     | Fabio     | 1
Graham     | Holst     | 2
India      | Joplin    | 2
```

Comment: To see what happens with a rollback wrap your inserts in a begin transaction/rollback transaction. Then run it 4-5 times. Then one more time changing to a commit. Then look at the values in the table. Your sequence is incremented in this case which is probably not what you nor the OP intend to happen. :)

Comment: I don't think there is any way of doing this that would cater for rollbacks, deletes, etc. Unless you want to renumber on delete then there is no way out. I'll up-vote this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use identity column + computed column. Sure it's two columns instead of one, but it's good to have identity column for a primary key anyway.

```
create table #t(data varchar(50), id int identity(0,1), increment as convert(int, id / 3))

insert into #t (data) select 'test1'
insert into #t (data) select 'test2'
insert into #t (data) select 'test3'
insert into #t (data) select 'test4'
insert into #t (data) select 'test5'
insert into #t (data) select 'test6'
insert into #t (data) select 'test7'
insert into #t (data) select 'test8'
insert into #t (data) select 'test9'

select * from #t
```

Comment: I like the identity option because it saves the order of inserts without respect to the increment column.  Also, OP is lacking a primary key, which is bad practice and not 1NF.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do such `Increment` *1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3* is to create a `SEQUENCE` :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MySeq AS INT  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 
    MAXVALUE 3 
    MINVALUE 1
    CYCLE;  
GO 

CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    FirstName VARCHAR(50)
    , LastName VARCHAR(50)
    , Increment INT --CONSTRAINT IncrementDefault DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [MySeq]/3)
)
GO

INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName, Increment) SELECT 'Alice','Bell', ( NEXT VALUE FOR [MySeq])
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName, Increment) SELECT 'Charlie','Dickens', ( NEXT VALUE FOR [MySeq])
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName, Increment) SELECT 'Ernest','Fabio', ( NEXT VALUE FOR [MySeq])
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName, Increment) SELECT 'Graham','Holst', ( NEXT VALUE FOR [MySeq])
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName, Increment) SELECT 'India','Joplin', ( NEXT VALUE FOR [MySeq])

SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY Increment ASC;
```

Results:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| FirstName | LastName | Increment |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
| Alice     | Bell     |         1 |
| Graham    | Holst    |         1 |
| India     | Joplin   |         2 |
| Charlie   | Dickens  |         2 |
| Ernest    | Fabio    |         3 |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Not sure you need an instead of trigger here. But that is one way of handling it.